# Backbone Marionette: templateHelpers and itemViewOptions

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I've a problem with Backbone Marionette and ItemView rendering. 
I need to pass a value from the Composite View to each of its Item View.
The value is contained correctly in the options array of the Item View, however, I cannot access it from the templateHelpers method.

So I tried to set it as value of my View but when I render the array it returns an "undefined" value.

**The Composite View**

```
var TableView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
....
    itemViewOptions: {
        foo: "bar",
    },
```

**The Item View**

```
var RowView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

template: RowTemplate,
tagName: "tr",
foo: "",

initialize: function(){

    this.foo = this.options.foo;              
},

templateHelpers: {  

     foo: function(){
         return this.foo;
     }

},
```

What I'm doing wrong? How can I access the value and fetch it to the template? Thank you.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In the `templateHelpers` functions, the `this` variable is the object that was retured from the `serializeData` method. To get the `itemViewOptions` in to the `templateHelpers`, then, you need to modify the `serializeData` method on your item view:

```
ItemView.extend({

  // ...

  serializeData: function(){
    // call the super method
    var data = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.prototype.serializeData.apply(this, arguments);

    // augment the data the way you need
    data.foo = this.options.foo;

    // send back your custom data
    return data;
  }


});
```

This should make your data available in the `templateHelpers`.

Comment: Exactly what I needed to get an option into the spark template.

Answer (score 12):

More simple solution use construction `templateHelpers: function(){return {}}`, example:

```
var RowView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    // ...
    templateHelpers: function(){  
        return {
            foo: this.foo
        }
    },
    // ...
})
```

and for using with data:

```
var RowView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    // ...
    templateHelpers: function(){
        var foo = this.foo  // context is view
        return {
            something: function(){ 
                return this.name + " " + foo  // context is data object
            }
        }
    },
    // ...
})
```

Docs: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.view.md#object-or-function-as-templatehelpers

Comment: To call this function inside the template I'd invoke it like this: `something()`?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is simpler

in your view

```
var RowView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
...
 initialize: function(options){
            this.options = options;
        },
        options: {},
  templateHelpers: function(){
        var foo = this.options.foo;
....

}
```

the benefit of this is if you have other things you want to pass values to they can just take it from options, for example in one of my views I have

```
 className: function(){ return this.options.size + "-widget"; }
```

for a collection of widgets.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling the super method as Derick suggested

```
var data = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.prototype.serializeData.apply(this, arguments);
```

Be sure to call it on a proper class like `CompositeView` instead of `ItemView`, because since Marionette 2.2 `SerializeData` fn has been changed to pass on implementation logic to specific functions and not all of the are available in all classes

Or alternatively if you are using CoffeeScript, you can call `data = super(arguments)`